# How to set certain columns to Bubble Chart dataLabel in highcharts (Rcharts)?

Tags: highcharts, shiny, rcharts

How to set "prd_nm" column to bubble chart's data label?
I try to use "plot Options : format" option, but i can't find it.

`data <-  top30`

```
 colnames(data) <- c('prd_rk', 'prd_nm', 'category', 'strategy', 'plc', 
'sales', 'purchases', 'customers', 'age', 'purchase_rate', 
'repurchase_rate')

hc <- hPlot(sales ~ purchases, data = data, type = "bubble", size = 
"customers", group = "strategy")

hc$plotOptions(series=list(dataLabels=list(enabled=TRUE, formmat= . 
{"y"})))

hc$set(height = 500)

hc$colors(palette)

hc
```

Comment: improve formatting

Comment: Hi ash, here you can find an example how to set dataLabels for bubble series from an external data source: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/whsqe1b4/

Answer (score 0):

You have a little typo there with **formmat**. Please try to change your code to:

```
hc$plotOptions(series=list(dataLabels=list(enabled=TRUE, format="{prd_nm}")))
```

Comment: thank you. but, your code also shows the data label as y value, not prd_nm